# A digital sum question

Tags: number-theory

Given a perfect square with digit sum $n$, can we find another perfect square with digit sum $4n$?
I was trying to prove this, but I couldn't. Thanks.

EDIT:
I don't know why this was downvoted, without a reason. Anyways, the actual question given was to

> Show there is a perfect square with digit sum $4^n$ for all $n$.

Now this was the inductive step. Now I thought in the lines of this, take a perfect square $s^2$ with digit sum $4^n$, let $s$ have $k$ digits. Now, if I could find appropriate powers of $10$ then $s^2\cdot (10^{2m}+2\cdot 10^m+1)$ would be a perfect square, with its digit sum 4 times $s^2$ because it would be like $\overline{s^2}00\dots 00\overline{s^2}00\dots 00\overline{s^2}00\dots 00\overline{s^2} $ this or something else. But I can't seem to find a configuration like this. I had found this :
$4\mapsto (4\cdot 10+1)^2=1681$ and note $1681$ has digit sum $16=4^2$ but couldn't proceed further. Hope this is shedding enough light on it.

Comment: Okay, so what did you try? :)

Comment: I don't think such a set actually exist. Take for eg 16 which is a perfect square, sum of digits is 7. 4 times 7 makes it 28. That's a digit sum of 9991 and that's not a perfect square. Do you have such a number in mind.?

Comment: See the edit, hope it is clarified a bit @Shaun. And Sid we have to find another perfect square having the digital sum $4n$, but we cannot say any number with digit sum $4n$ will be a perfect square. And downvoter, please try to see if this is upto your likings. Thanks for such friendly gestures.

Comment: What if you take a number of the form $$100\dots00100\dots001\dots1$$ with $2^n$ ones and lots of zeros between the ones, and square it? Seems to me you could arrange to get a digit sum $4^n$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Can you please emphasise on your idea? I tried to do it, but I can't find the right way. I don't see how we can ensure, a digit sum of $4^n$.Thanks for helping.

Comment: It turns out I posted an answer to a harder problem a while ago. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183333/integer-sequence-sums-of-digits-of-squares/183518#183518 where you'll see how to show that given any positive integer $s$ congruent to 0, 1, 4, or 7 modulo 9 (and that includes all powers of 4) there's an integer $n$ such that the digits of $n^2$ add up to $s$.

Comment: Well, @GerryMyerson sorry for being so blunt, but how does those statements finish the problems? Could you help me a bit here? Thanks a lot. Please explain it a bit. My apologies for being unable to get it.

Comment: $8^2=64$ has digit sum $10$. $98^2=9604$ has digit sum $19$. $998^2=996004$ has digit sum $28$. $9998^2=99960004$ has digit sum $37$. And so on. So, every number that's $1$ modulo $9$ is the digit sum of a square. In particular, $4^3=64$ is the digit sum of $9999998^2$. Does that help?

Comment: Are you still there?

Comment: Forgive me @GerryMyerson for not responding, well your solution sums up it very nicely. Again my apologies for you, I am sorry for my rudeness.

Comment: All's well that ends well.

Comment: Thank you for being so great. But I am too ashamed now, for this meaningless rude behaviour.